# Do WHERE IN queries reindex the table after each set within the query?

Tags: mysql, index, performance, where, query-performance

I have a basic WHERE IN query that takes too long (30+ secs) to process.

```
DELETE FROM `table1`
WHERE ( djID, localID )
IN (("128","26"),("110","32"))
```

The table I'm querying on has about 20 million rows, with two indices - the first is the auto-incremented PK named ID, the second index is over two columns - `djID`, `localID`

I'm wondering if MySQL re-indexes the table after each ( djID, localID ) in the query, therefore accounting for the long query time, and if so, is there a way to force it to wait until all the ( djID, localID ) sets have been executed in the query before re-indexing?

Or is there another reason jumping out that may cause the long query time?

Comment: What mysql version do you use?

Comment: How many rows are deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No `SELECT` causes reindexing.  Only `ALTER`, `OPTIMIZE`, and a few other commands, *may* cause reindexing.
2. The construct (a,b) IN ((1,2), (3,4)) is not well optimized.

So,...  Make it two `DELETEs`, such as

```
DELETE FROM `table1`
    WHERE djID = 128
      AND localID = 26;
```

If you have lots of them, you could build a tmp table with the pairs of numbers, then do a multi-table `DELETE`.

To demonstrate that it is doing far more work than it ought to,

```
FLUSH STATUS;
DELETE ... WHERE ... IN ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

You will probably see some numbers about 20M (or maybe 40M), indicating that it did a table scan in spite of having the index.

Then file a bug with http://bugs.mysql.com (unless there already is one).

Comment: `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE (djID = 128 AND localID = 26) OR (djID = 110 AND localID = 32) ;` should use the index as well.

Comment: If the pairs aren't many, perhaps the temporary table could be replaced with a derived one along the lines of `(SELECT '128' AS djID, '26' AS localID UNION ALL SELECT '110', '32') AS tmp`.

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ - the optimizer did not used to be smart enough to the obvious index.  `OR` pretty much turned off the optimizer.  Do you have evidence to the contrary now?

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't get to this before as I was on holiday - I will try out the suggestions this week.

Comment: @Rick James - am I able to hire you as a consultant to help code the multi table delete?

Comment: @Shaun - yes.  Contact me at se at rjweb.org to discuss further.